# How to find all "Blank" Cells using ClosedXML and Replace it with Dash("-")

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx, closedxml

I'm looking for ways to find the blank Cells on an Excel (xlsx) file using the ClosedXML and replace it with Dash(`-`) in two ways:

1. Given the Range `ex("A1:l15")`
2. With no range but must be able to detect the blank cells in between the last cells used per row or per column.

My current code is:

```
string path = txtPath.Text;

var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(txtWorksheet.Text);
var range =  worksheet.Range(txtMinRange + ":" + txtMaxRange);
```

I'm stuck as to what approach should I use to find all the blanks in the specified Range.

Should I go through all Rows? Is there a method that finds all blank cells an just replace it with dash?

I hope my questions make sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like ([mcve])? Also: Avoid phrasing your question with *"best way"* - that will likely get your question closed for being primarily opinion-based or too broad.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm quite new here so I don't know much about the format in posting questions here in Stakoverflow. Here's hoping for your guidance.

Comment: Introduction: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't forget about the topics in the yellow side-bar, they are quite important. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Do you want a real dash or do you mean the accounting number format?